# Undefined reference to `main' C++ error in eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have program with 3 classes when I try to great oop in main I have errors.  I try to change command of gcc with other posts in stack but error doesn't change. What am I missing?

My project name is temp and has Region, Sensor and Network classes.
I try this command `gcc Region_temp.c -o Region_temp`.

```
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2  
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 13    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 21 has invalid symbol index 22    
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2  
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13 
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2  
make: *** [temp] Error 1
undefined reference to main
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Region.h"
using namespace std;
namespace personalization {
    int main() {

        int t ;
        for ( cin >> t ; t != 0; t--){     // reads t different test cases .

            Region region ;

             while(true)
            {
                 int sn , temp;
                 cin >> sn >> temp;
                 if (sn == 0 && temp == 0)
                     break;
                 region.add_sensor(sn , temp) ;
            }
             while (true)
            {
                 int sn1 , sn2 ;
                 cin >> sn1 >> sn2 ;
                 if (sn1 == 0 && sn2 == 0)
                     break;
                 if ( ! ( region . same_network(sn1 , sn2 ) ) )
                     region.join_networks (sn1 , sn2 ) ;
            }
             cout << region . num_of_networks ( ) << " " << region . max_avg_temp ( ) << endl ;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code example?

Comment: @AndreasDM I attach them in my question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `main` function in a namespace. The compiler (linker) can't find it if you do that. Remove it from the namespace.

```
int main() {

        int t ;
        for ( cin >> t ; t != 0; t--){     // reads t different test cases .

            Region region ;

             while(true)
            {
                 int sn , temp;
                 cin >> sn >> temp;
                 if (sn == 0 && temp == 0)
                     break;
                 region.add_sensor(sn , temp) ;
            }
             while (true)
            {
                 int sn1 , sn2 ;
                 cin >> sn1 >> sn2 ;
                 if (sn1 == 0 && sn2 == 0)
                     break;
                 if ( ! ( region . same_network(sn1 , sn2 ) ) )
                     region.join_networks (sn1 , sn2 ) ;
            }
             cout << region . num_of_networks ( ) << " " << region . max_avg_temp ( ) << endl ;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You also need to add just above main "using namespace personalization;"

Comment: My error doesn't change when i don't use `namespace std;`

Comment: @girl71 , Chol Nhial addressed this in his first comment. I recommend editing the answer to add that note formally.

Comment: @Chol: You can put the using statement *inside* main too.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc Region_temp.c -o Region_temp` the "-o" will cause the compiler look for a main() in Region_temp.c and try to make a binary named Region_temp

try `gcc -c Region_temp.c` followed by `g++ Region_temp.o main.cpp -o Region_temp`

while you are at it, you may want to rename c++ files to .cpp and use g++ to compile them

Edit: now that the code sample is posted, @Chol Nhial has correctly observed that you also name-spaced your main() ... don't do that.

Comment: sorry i confused ,in picture where i use this command that you say

Comment: @girl71 those are command line commands to be used in a terminal (not for running inside eclipse).  Just run them in a terminal, you'll learn a lot more that way anyhow.

Comment: tnx , yes i'm new in c++ and linux